# Base64 encoded message issue with webservice for mobile app

Tags: php, android, ios, mysql, mobile-application

we are posting some message from website and displaying it on the mobile app.
We are storing the message in base64 encoded format in mysql database.
For mobile app we are giving the base64 encoded string, and mobile developer are doing decoding from there side and displaying the normal text.
Now issue is when we are using '**enter, single quote, double quote**' this characters are displayed as ' **\n, \' and \"** '  like this.

Is there any solution for this that this will displayed correctly in the android and iphone app.
or what we can do this from php server side.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed` instead of `NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength` parameter in iOS while converting base64 into normal string using `base64EncodedStringWithOptions` method

```
NSString *strNormalText = [yourBase64Data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed];
```

Try these below parameters if needed :

```
NSDataBase64Encoding76CharacterLineLength
NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithCarriageReturn
```

#### Note : In Android same option might be available

Comment: Its not working for me. can you please suggest something else. I am using utf8